# How do I get a pickaxe in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm just starting out in Minecraft Pocket Edition, and I can't figure out how to get a pickaxe. How do I make a pickaxe?

Comment: Please, do some research (and show that you have done so) before posting a question. The [Minecraft wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki) is a great resource for answering a question like this.

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this question. That said, downvotes do indicate that "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 9):

To craft a pickaxe in Pocket Edition, you're going to first need to punch some trees. Get at least 3 or 4 logs, then go into your crafting menu (hit the "..." in your inventory, then tap "Craft") and craft these into planks. You're going to want to make a crafting table and a set of sticks as well. Place the crafting table, and just tap it to use it. From here, you should be able to craft a wooden pickaxe with 3 wooden planks and 2 sticks.

[image: Crafting menu showing a pickaxe.]

For more crafting recipes, check out [this guide](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/Multiformat/Minecraft+-+Pocket+Edition/feature.asp?c=43958) for a complete list.

Comment: Thank you! Apologies I am trying to help my 8 year old son :)

Comment: @Nat No worries! :)

Answer (score 0):

YOU only get hoe's and swords in creative mode 
In survival you first must chop down trees craft the wood into planks then create  Some sticks then a crafting table go to tools you should be able to Make a pick axe

Answer (score 0):

Collect some wood go to a crafting table and use any block diamond,gold,iron,stone or wood then you will see a pick axe icon on the screen click it and you will have a pickaxe

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a pickaxe in Minecraft PE you must first have a crafting table.

1. Turn two pieces of wood into wood planks and creating crafting table.
2. Place your crafting table down somewhere.
3. Gather more wood and turn them into sticks. (You will need 2-4 sticks and wood planks to build the top 'pick' part of the pickaxe.

With that pickaxe you can mine cobblestone and build a cobblestone pickaxe using basically the same instructions.

Comment: Hi Candy, welcome to Arqade! Whilst this is an OK answer, this doesn't cover much that the top answer hasn't already said.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you have to get wood and make sticks on the crafting table. If you go to the weapons spot you'll see that there is a wood pickaxe. Is white spelling. That is how you make a wood pickaxe.

Comment: This does not add any information that [Unionhawk's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152338/12936) doesn't cover...